# Add user_id to nested_attributes with strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Can anyone please advice me on what's a best practive on adding user_id to nested models on parent model create/update ?

Let's say i have a `Band` model with many `Song` models assigned. Any user can edit a `Band` info and add any `Song`s using `fields_for` method in a view. `Songs` table has a `user_id` column, which should be populated with `current_user.id`.

I'm trying to figure out how to handle that in my `BandsController` using strong parameters but without any luck.

BandsController `band_params` method look more or less like that:

```
def band_params
  params.require(:band).permit(
    :name, :location, :city, :country_name, :country_code,
    songs_attributes: [:id, :name, :duration, :_destroy]
  )
end
```

I can hack that method and iterate through each `songs_attributes` element adding user id but isn't there any better / more secure / build-in functionality for such operation? If not, what's the most sufficient way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want each song to have a user_id?  Not each band?

Comment: Yes, i need to know which user has created a song and creating a song is available just from `fields_for` section of band form.

Comment: I wrote a gem that will set created_by_id and updated_by_id automatically during save - https://github.com/house9/clerk - with rails 4 you have to install from git (at the moment)

Comment: nice stuff @house9! That's exactly what i was looking for :) Post it as a answer and i'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: ok - added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a gem that will set `created_by_id` and `updated_by_id` automatically during save - https://github.com/house9/clerk

if you are using rails 4 you must install using git

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your band already exists before a song is added:

```
def update
    @band = Band.find(params[:id])
    @band.user = current_user
    @band.update_attributes(band_params)      
end
```

If you create the band and song at the same time:

```
def create
    @band = Band.new(band_params)
    @band.user = current_user
    @band.save      
end
```

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  I am changing my answer and will post it shortly.

Comment: Sure thing ;) Please have in mind that band do have a `user_id` column but it's not always the same as song's `user_id`. I need to know which user has added a song to band, that's why.

Comment: What is your application supposed to do.  From what I've heard so far, I'm not sure your app is as restful as it could be.

Comment: Let's say i'm creating a wiki-styled database of bands and songs they've written. User can create a Band entry but he also can assign a songs to the band using a nested form. There is no way to create a song other than by this nested form. I need to store id of user that created a song.